# shape distortion when rotating model matrix

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix, glm-math

I'm attempting to rotate a shape using the glm library in conjunction with openGL. Unfortunately, when I attempt to rotate the shape using glm::rotate(), my shape's dimensions become stretched. Alongside this, the shape rotates around a seemingly random point. Everything is 2 dimensional.

Vertex Shader Code:

```
#version 330 core

layout(location = 0) in vec2 pos;
uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 projection;
uniform mat4 view;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = projection * view * model * vec4(pos.x, pos.y, 1.0f, 1.0f);
}
```

Model Matrix Code:

```
m_angle = angle;
m_modelMatrix = glm::rotate(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::radians((float)m_angle), glm::vec3(0, 0, 1));
```

Projection and View Matrices Code:

```
glm::mat4 proj = glm::mat4(1.0f);
glm::mat4 view = glm::mat4(1.0f);
proj = glm::perspective(glm::radians(53.f), 1.f, 0.1f, 100.f);
view = glm::translate(view, glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -3.0f));
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is caused because the projection matrix doesn't take care of the aspect ration of the viewport. In your code the *aspect* parameter is *1.0*:

> ```cpp
> proj = glm::perspective(glm::radians(53.f), 1.f, 0.1f, 100.f);
> ```

The aspect parameter has to to be the ratio of the width and height of the viewprot respectively window:

```cpp
float aspect = (float)window_width/(float)window_height;
proj = glm::perspective(glm::radians(53.f), aspect, 0.1f, 100.f);
```

Comment: i have been messing with this parameter. when i set it to 1.f, all shapes have the proper dimensions and none are stretched, and the rotations do not work. but when it is simply 1.f, the shapes are not stretched except for the rotated ones.

Comment: @cummiesinmytummy Probably you compensate the rectangular viewport by the view or model matrix. That is wrong. If you want to draw a square, then the length of the sides has to be the equal and the view and model matrix do no scale or scale uniformly in all directions. The rectangular viewport has to be compensated by the projection matrix. There is no other solution.  Read [Camera](https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Camera)